# Unable to import gpdraw in Java

Tags: java, import

I am unable to import the class gpdraw in java.

```
import gpdraw.*;
```

This is the import statement I used. I  double and triple checked it - it's definitely correct- but it keeps throwing the exception *package gpdraw does not exist*. Can anyone think of why?
I use Bluej on a Macbook, if that helps.

Comment: Have you included the library in your compile/runtime classpath?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gpdraw is not included in Java per default. As MadProgrammer pointed out, you have to include the library in your compile/runtime classpath.

- BlueJ:

  > The first way is via the "Preferences" dialog. Open the "Preferences" dialogue and select the "Libraries" tab. Then add the location where your classes are as a library path. Restart BlueJ - done. The selected libraries will now be available in all projects that you open.
  >   (http://www.bluej.org/faq.html)
- Command:

  > ```
  > javac -sourcepath src -classpath path/to/gpdraw.jar
  > ```
  >
  > (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=637270)